# Add a new column with lowest value within groups

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe such as :

```
Groups Value Element 
G1     1     A
G1     4     B
G1     6     C
G2     2     D
G2     1     E
G3     7     F
G3     4     G
G3     2     H
G3     2     I
```

And I would like to add a newcolumn called `first_Element` which would be for each `Groups` the **Element** with the **lowest** `Value`, if there are ex aequo, then take the first one.

I should then get :

```
Groups Value Element first_Element
G1     1     A       A
G1     4     B       A
G1     6     C       A
G2     2     D       E
G2     1     E       E
G3     7     F       H
G3     4     G       H
G3     2     H       H
G3     2     I       H
```

Does some one have an idea please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = df.merge(pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('Groups').apply(lambda x: x['Element'][x['Value'].idxmin()]), columns=['first_Element']).reset_index(), on='Groups')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Groups  Value Element first_Element
0     G1      1       A             A
1     G1      4       B             A
2     G1      6       C             A
3     G2      2       D             E
4     G2      1       E             E
5     G3      7       F             H
6     G3      4       G             H
7     G3      2       H             H
8     G3      2       I             H
```

Answer (score 2):

User `groupby().transform` with `idxmin`, then `loc` accesss:

```
min_loc = df.groupby('Groups')['Value'].transform('idxmin')

df['first_element'] = df.loc[min_loc, 'Element'].to_numpy()
```

Output:

```
  Groups  Value Element first_element
0     G1      1       A             A
1     G1      4       B             A
2     G1      6       C             A
3     G2      2       D             E
4     G2      1       E             E
5     G3      7       F             H
6     G3      4       G             H
7     G3      2       H             H
8     G3      2       I             H
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using map:

```
(df.assign(first_Element = df['Groups'].map(df.loc[df.groupby('Groups')['Value'].idxmin()]
                                            .set_index('Groups')['Element'])))
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to sort the values, group, then select the first values per group:

```py
first = (df.sort_values(['Groups', 'Value'])
           .groupby('Groups', sort = False)
           .Element
           .transform('first')
         )
df.assign(first_Element = first)
 
  Groups  Value Element first_Element
0     G1      1       A             A
1     G1      4       B             A
2     G1      6       C             A
3     G2      2       D             E
4     G2      1       E             E
5     G3      7       F             H
6     G3      4       G             H
7     G3      2       H             H
8     G3      2       I             H
```

Another option is to sort the values, drop duplicates and merge back to the original dataframe; this avoids a groupby, and *might* be more efficient (just an assumption):

```py
trimmed = (df.sort_values(['Groups', 'Value'])
             .drop(columns='Value')
             .drop_duplicates(subset='Groups')
             .rename(columns={'Element':'first_Element'})
           )

df.merge(trimmed, on='Groups')
 
  Groups  Value Element first_Element
0     G1      1       A             A
1     G1      4       B             A
2     G1      6       C             A
3     G2      2       D             E
4     G2      1       E             E
5     G3      7       F             H
6     G3      4       G             H
7     G3      2       H             H
8     G3      2       I             H
```